# Observable.fromEventPattern TypedEventHandler

Tags: c#, linq, reactive-programming, hid, reactiveui

I am able to generate an Observable from HID Input Report events, but I would like to dive in to the packet data with Linq queries.

I am having trouble making all the types line up.

```
readerPackets = Observable
    .FromEventPattern
        <TypedEventHandler<HidDevice, HidInputReportReceivedEventArgs>,
        HidDevice,
        HidInputReportReceivedEventArgs>(
            h => reader.InputReportReceived += h,
            h => reader.InputReportReceived -= h)
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
```

This works without the .Select.  When I add the select I get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IObservable<Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.HidInputReportReceivedEventArgs>' to 'System.IObservable<System.Reactive.EventPattern<Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.HidDevice,Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.HidInputReportReceivedEventArgs>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I have tried casting with the types listed in the error, but apparently I am missing something because I can never make it happy.

Can you tell what cast type I should use and where it should be placed?

Comment: What type is `readerPackets`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  The compiler highlights the select line as the error.  The real error was the type of "readerPackets".  By adjusting that type I was able to make the code functional.